# OpenID Connect ID Token: What's the purpose of audience [aud] field validation

Tags: security, microservices, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement [OpenID Connect Implicit Flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth). The frontend Single Page App passes the ID Token down to the backend server (using Authorization header) where I need to validate it.

The documentation requires me [to check](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation) that I trust the audience of the token (aud & azp fields). I'm struggling to understand the significance of this validation step and what are the security implications of not doing so. Why should I distrust the token if I'm not the intended recipient?

My reasoning is that if I trust the issuer it doesn't matter who was the token issued for. I would expect the claims to be the same for any clientId (is this wrong?). Ideally when I pass the ID Token around my microservices all they should know is what issuers to trust (and use [discovery protocol](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig) for figuring out the keys).

What is the attack vector if I skip this validation step?

Answer (score 14):

The issuer could be issuing tokens to different applications and those applications could have different permissions. Not checking the audience would allow an attacker to use a token issued for application A at application B and may lead to permission elevation.

To your suggestion: the claims may indeed differ per Client.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another reason: If you check that aud claim only contains your client, it prevents other apps' stolen tokens from being used on your app. If a user's token gets stolen from another app, nobody will be able to impersonate the user on your app because the aud claim will not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this for posterity.

You should check the issuer and if your client_id is the only one in the audience if you are receiving tokens from an external OpenId Provider. One that could have more than your client.

Claims are not global to the OpenID Provider, they can be per-client. A user can have "Admin" role on app-A, gets a token there, then tries to send app-B (your application) the same token hoping that your are not checking to which client it was issued for (its audience).